# Angular directive repeating after function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

**Hello!**

I have a question regarding the ability to use ng-repeat for a custom directive that is used to plot a chart using D3.js.

If I have variable that is initialized via a function that is triggered by button, is there some way to use said variable with ng-repeat?

**Code example:**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('controller'function app($scope) {
    $scope.getData = function () {
        //get something via a http request using selected_id;
        return return_val;
    };
    app.directive('chart', function () {
        //directive code here,
    });
};

<body>
    <form ng-submit="getData()">
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" ng-model="selected_id">checkbox</input>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <chart ng-repeat="item in return_val" ng-if="return_val" val="return_val[$index]"></chart>
</body>
```

Is there a way to make the chart tag initialize only when the getData function is run so that it uses the value of **return_val[$index]** when plotting? In this example I would like to get one graph for every element in return_val when it is changed by getData().

How would I need to change my code to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [`https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

You can set a scope variable using the promise that the $http request return's `.success` function.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('controller'function app($scope, $http) {
  $scope.getData = function () {
    $http.get('something').success(function(result) {
      $scope.results = result.values;
    });
  }
});

<body>
  <form ng-submit="getData()">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" ng-model="selected_id">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
  <chart ng-repeat="item in results" ng-if="results" val="item"></chart>
</body>
```

Comment: You're absolutely correct. It was simply a matter of me not using the correct ng-if variable! Thank you good sir!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, what are you trying to achieve.

second, your directive should never be inside your controller. The main reason for the existence of directives is for SOC.

Your script should probably be like follows:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('ctrl', function app($scope) {
    $scope.getData = function () {
        return_val = [{ id: 'A', value: 10 }, { id: 'B', value: 12 }];
        $scope.return_val = return_val;
    };
});
 app.directive('chart', function () {
        return {
          template: '<h5>{{item.id}} : {{item.value}}</h5>',
          restrict: 'AE',
          replace: true,
          scope: false
        }
  });
```

```html
<html ng-app='app'>

<head>
  <script src='https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js'></script>
  <script src='script.js'></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller='ctrl'>
  <form ng-submit="getData()">
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" ng-model="selected_id" /> checkbox
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
  <chart ng-repeat="item in return_val" ng-if="return_val" val="return_val[$index]"></chart>
</body>

</html>
```